# Fix Corrupted Loose Git Head in Windows

Tags: git, file, corrupt, loose

My computer shut down due to a kernal panic I lost my git repo on my virtual machine which is in Windows. When I go on .net I get the following error:

```
corrupted loose reference file: HEAD
```

I have in place a folder called .git that contains a list of my branches.

[image]
Is there a way I can convert this back to a git entity? Or would I have to reclone the directory?

Comment: All the other files are gone and only the .git is remaining?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal my files are there, except I no longer have git there

Comment: I see, then possibly you will loose all your unpushed commits, stash etc. You can get it back to working without cloning (meaning, keeping your local changes).  You can remove the .git folder, and re initiate a git repo, then set the remotes and simply do a fetch? I guess it would work

Comment: output of `git status`, `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --branches --all`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're showing in your `.git` directory is not a list of branches; it's the standard structure for git repo metadata.  This includes a few symbolic refs, such as `HEAD`.  When a ref is stored as a file on disk, it's called a "loose" ref, which is what I believe the error message is talking about.

So the error seems to indicate that the file `.git/HEAD` is corrupt.  That in itself is not hard to fix (though most git commands won't work since they won't currently recognize that this is a repo, so it will take a bit of a kludge); the bigger question, in the wake of a sudden system crash, is whether anything else is also corrupt.  But as a starting point, you might try something like

```
# back up .git/HEAD somewhere, just in case
echo 'ref: refs/heads/master` >.git/HEAD
```

Now hopefully your repo will be recognized again.  Next it would be smart to do some checks like

```
git fsck
```

and maybe checking if you have expected changes on expected branches.

The most vulnerable thing would be uncommitted changes (and especially unstaged changes).  But at least if the above steps go well, you can assess the damage and decide where to go from there.

Comment: getting the head back was all I needed. This worked, thanks!

Comment: Seems like  a good solution. Does `git fsck` verify that everything is fine and nothing else is corrupted? I've seen that git used to work normally even when git objects are deleted (but not sure how it would work if corrupted).

Comment: I don't know that you could say it checks everything, but I'd be reasonably comfortable using a repo that passed an `fsck`.  Of course, if worried, one could validate anything that only exists locally, then store those things to a bundle, then re-clone the repo and re-apply the bundle

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to your previous stage without cloning the repository again. You might be able to keep your local changes, but you will lose all your unpushed commits or stashes.

This is what I would do:

1. Take a backup of your git repository. (just copy it in case you need anything).
2. remove the .git folder (in linux, `rm -rf .git`)
3. `git init`
4. `git remote add origin <your remote repository url>`
5. `git fetch`
6. `git reset origin/<the last branch you were in>`

> This is important: If you were in the `Development` branch, then give it as `origin/Development`.

Now everything should be back in place. If you run `git status`, you should see your modified files etc.

This is only a suggestion. You can copy your folder and give it a try and see :)

Edit: I have missed to include an important step. You need to fetch after you add the origin.

Hope it would work for you :)

Comment: I think I would at least try to salvage the local repo first.  If all that's known to be wrong is the `HEAD` ref, that's not hard to fix; and we don't know how much they'd be discarding by throwing out the local .git folder.

Comment: worked great! my situation was as follows: after resolving some conflicts, we have commit the changes, then found a merge error, fixed that, tried to commit that. VM stopped responding, process failed. this has resulted in corruption somewhere in git folder. We were able to recover all unpushed changes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by doing the following:

1. Zip your repo just in case you remove the wrong thing
2. Use an editor (NotePad++ or VisualStudio Code) to search in all files for references to your bad branch. For example, in NotePad++ hit Ctrl+shft+F and looke for feature/my-bad-branch
3. Open the files with that reference and decide if you should remove the reference

- I only had to remove the branch from .git/config
- I didn't delete any references to it in logs

4. Look in the .git/refs/remotes/origin folder and subfolders for a file by the same name as your branch. For example .git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/my-bad-branch. Delete that file
5. Try to pull from the origin again